# Repackage update site into one feature

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an update site that contains some 100 - 200 features and many more plugins. For some users all of these are needed, so I'd like to simplify the installation process by creating one feature that they can install. This feature would then contain all the contents of the update site.

I've created a new feature project and my plan is to add the contents of the original update site as included features and plugins in this project.

Problems is; In my feature project, when adding feature in the "included features" tab, I can only add features that are currently installed in my Eclipse platform. I'd rather not install those 200 features just so I can add them.

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Just curious...you said that you don't want to install the feaures from your update site, but that you expect that users will?  Why would you expect users to want to install these 200 features if you don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the features installed in your target platform, you will need to edit the feature.xml file directly.  All you need to do is to add the following for each feature that you want to include:

```
<includes
     id="<add_feature_id>"
     version="0.0.0"/>
```

Your build process (PDE or tycho) should add the proper version numbers for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a detailed look at the Eclipse target platform concept. The features don't need to be installed in your current Eclipse platform (i.e. the IDE), they need to be installed in the target platform to be available for an update site.

If you never defined a target platform, your currently running application will be taken as IDE, and that is where your confusion might come from.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to manipulate a feature I only need to have them in my workspace. No reason to install them.